# AWS ECS task definition workflow

Tags: terraform, amazon-ecs, github-actions

I've setup one of my services to be deployed to ECS (EC2). I have the service and task definition configured via terraform and then to deploy I'm using Github actions where it seems I need to define the task definition again.

It seems both are required, what would be the correct workflow so I can remove the duplicate task definition?

There's also the problem of once this task definition has been deployed via Github actions, the image has been updated which terraform wants to revert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an old one but for future reference.

The first one is required in order to bring up the service initially (while creating your pre-configured cluster).

You can consider the second one as an option to update your [service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/update-service.html) (deploy a new version of the image) over the initial one during your GitHub Actions deployment (as you can change the image id and basically everything that you have as a configuration option in the task definition).

With regard to terraform you can add a lifecycle rule to ignore any changes to the pre-configured image_id with something like this in the **aws_ecs_service**:

```
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [task_definiton]
  }
```

There is [quite an old issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/632) in the terraform-provider-aws project with regard to how it handles task definition changes. Take a look at [this comment](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/632#issuecomment-707922431) for a possible workaround for your use case ([blog post on topic from the comment author](https://ianw.org/posts/ecs-terraform-continuous-delivery.html)).

Down below you can see [another comment](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/632#issuecomment-717079794) linking a [ready-to-go Github Actions solution with a terraform code example.](https://github.com/modum-io/aws-ecs-deploy-service-by-template)